# Directive not displaying data from service since changing directive's scope

Tags: angularjs

Currently have a directive that's template uses an ng-repeat to create a list of buttons. When using isolate scope the list populates but when, for necessary reasons, I change the scope to true the list no longer appears.

Here is a rough example of the code...

Directive Function

```
var list= function () {
    return {
        templateUrl: "list.html",
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            scope.id = scope.$eval(attrs.id);
            scope.header = scope.$eval(attrs.header);
            scope.items = scope.$eval(attrs.items);

            // button listeners...
        }
    };
};
```

Controller

```
var self = this;
self.duckItems = [];
self.gooseItems = [];

    dataSvc.getListItems()
    .then(function (response) {
                    self.duckItems = response.data;
                    self.gooseItems = _.union(self.gooseItems,   _.flatten(_.map(self.duckItems , function (duck) {
                        return _.map(duck.goose, function (goose) {
                            return {name: goose};
                        });
                    })));
                }, function (reason) {
                    console.log('crap ' + reason);
                });
```

Service

```
serviceModule.service('dataSvc', ['$http', function ($http) {
        var self = this;
        self.getListItems= function () {
            return $http.get('js/list_items.json');
        };
    }]);
```

Template

```
<ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="(item.selected ? 'RUIFW-selected' : '')" ng-click="click(item)">
            <label>{{ item.name }}</label>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.selected" />
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: `scope: true` is *not* isolate, it creates a child scope

Comment: Yea the issue is that when it is changed from isolate {} to true, for unmentioned reasons, the data doesn't display.

Comment: Because it inherits from parent :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friendly coder added a ng-if="dataHasLoaded" to the directives element and flipped it to true in the promise. We have success.

The issue was that the directive was loading before the service was done.